# TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object in wordcloud in pyhon

Tags: python, word-cloud

I am trying to build wordcloud using WordCloud funtion in Python using following syntax

```
df = sql_query1
df.isna().sum()
word_cloud2 = WordCloud(collocations = False, background_color = 'white').generate(df["BankComment"])
```

it throws following error

```
TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object
```

i tried to convert bankComment to string using following methods

```
df["BankComment"] = df["BankComment"].replace("/"," ")
df["BankComment"] = df["BankComment"].apply(lambda x: str(x))
```

but nothing worked
following are entries

```
|/BAI/469/BAI/REF-6215077H0196 /ENTRY-18 MAR PO...|
|/BAI/469/BAI/REF-6215077H0218 /ENTRY-18 MAR PO...\|
```

Comment: The fact that you're applying `str` via a lambda function to `df["BankComment"]` indicated that it is a list of values; yet according to the [documentation](https://amueller.github.io/word_cloud/generated/wordcloud.WordCloud.html), only text is expected. It seems like you're supposed to be just passing in one string and not a list of them. I could be wrong though. What makes you think it should work on a list of values?

Comment: actually I tried multiple methods to convert the column to string as from error it looked that it was not a string type, by mistake I shared only the last one. I troed following options   ~~~1. astype(str)
df['column_name'] = df['column_name'].astype(str)

2. values.astype(str)
df['column_name'] = df['column_name'].values.astype(str)

3. map(str)
df['column_name'] = df['column_name'].map(str)

4. apply(str)
df['column_name'] = df['column_name'].apply(str)~~~

Comment: All those methods are changing the type of the **values** that are **within** the dataframe, but you're passing the **dataframe _itself_**. So of course none of those methods will work.